# Sketch: resize bitmap assets to their original size in pixel

Tags: sketch-app

When I import bitmaps assets (or image files) in sketch, I usually scale them back and forth for the sake of the layout. At some later point I may be interested in get them back to their original size (in pixel), to check if I didn't stretch them to far or check that the inserted asset is the right one. For example.

My question is: is there a way for sketch to resize bitmaps to their original size in pixel? I tried to set the size to 100% but this makes it as wide as the dartboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a specific menu option for this: `Layer > Image > Set to Original Size`